# php what is the "database" keyword in a function definition

Tags: php

What does the "database" keyword indicate in the function def below?  I can't (easily) find documentation for this.

```
function __construct($arg1, $arg2, database $mysqli = NULL)
```

Comment: This means that `$mysqli` must be object of class `database`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is type hinting. It means that the variable, in this case `$mysqli`, should meet **at least one** of the following criteria:

1. an instance of database class;
2. an instance from a classe that inherits from a classe named Database;
3. an instance from a classe that implements an interface named Database.

Comment: ok, thanks.  and found answers here:  http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: @i_like_pi well, if my answer is correct, you could accept this as the correct answer to your question.

Comment: i tried to yesterday but SO put a 3 hour delay on acceptance!  thanks for your answer